# Declaring or including "behavior: url(PIE.htc);" globally

Tags: html, css

I an using "css3 pie " for making my site to compatible with IE 8

Bellow is the css code,like this i use several class with various designs. `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` works when declaring it into the each class but i should be declared in every classes in css .I need to know is there possibility of declaring it as global .

```
      .content { 
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;   
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        background: #EEFF99;
        behavior: url(PIE.htc); //for making IE 8 compatible 

          }.content { 
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;   
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
        background: #EEFF99;
          }
```

Comment: I have got the answer for the question posted above 

     *{behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);}


If it is declared this in the css file ,behavior will be applied to all the classes which are used in that css file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
.content, .otherclass, .someclass {
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

If you're using Sass you could do the following:

```
.cssPie {
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.myFirstClass {
    @extend .cssPie;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.mySecondClass {
    @extend .cssPie;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,just now got the answer ,it can be declared as  `*{behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);}` to apply the behavior to all the css classes.

Comment: @Rajesh Please accept my answer if your happy. Also I don't recommend you to add this property to the universal selector `*` since this can cause heavy performance issues.